# Filter certain ID vars based on combination of start date and value

Tags: r, dplyr

```
structure(list(Stock = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), class =     "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(17632, 17633, 17634, 17632, 17633, 17634, 
    17632, 17633, 17634, 17632, 17633, 17634), class = "Date"), 
    Price = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 30L, 
    50L), Market.Cap = c(1000L, 1300L, 1600L, 1600L, 1000L, 1000L, 
    600L, 600L, 600L, 400L, 1000L, 2000L)), .Names = c("Stock", 
"Date", "Price", "Market.Cap"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class =     "data.frame")
```

I'm trying to filter this example according to Market Cap on a specific day. For example, I'm trying to remove stock BBB because it's the only one with market cap > 1500 on 2018-04-11. But stocks can remain in the data frame if market cap grows beyond 1500, like AAA and DDD. I tried dplyr but can't come up with the combination to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a grouped `filter`. The trick is to realise that [a grouped filter is really a grouped mutate then an ungrouped filter](http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#grouped-mutates-and-filters). To understand why, consider the comparable code at the end that gives the same result. We just need to see if for each stock, `any` of the rows have both a particular date and an excessive market cap.

```r
df <- structure(list(Stock = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("AAA", "BBB", "CCC", "DDD"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(17632, 17633, 17634, 17632, 17633, 17634, 17632, 17633, 17634, 17632, 17633, 17634), class = "Date"), Price = c(5L, 6L, 7L, 10L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 30L, 50L), Market.Cap = c(1000L, 1300L, 1600L, 1600L, 1000L, 1000L, 600L, 600L, 600L, 400L, 1000L, 2000L)), .Names = c("Stock", "Date", "Price", "Market.Cap"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")

library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  group_by(Stock) %>%
  filter(!any(Market.Cap > 1500 & Date == as.Date("2018-04-11")))
#> # A tibble: 9 x 4
#> # Groups:   Stock [3]
#>   Stock Date       Price Market.Cap
#>   <fct> <date>     <int>      <int>
#> 1 AAA   2018-04-11     5       1000
#> 2 AAA   2018-04-12     6       1300
#> 3 AAA   2018-04-13     7       1600
#> 4 CCC   2018-04-11     6        600
#> 5 CCC   2018-04-12     6        600
#> 6 CCC   2018-04-13     6        600
#> 7 DDD   2018-04-11    10        400
#> 8 DDD   2018-04-12    30       1000
#> 9 DDD   2018-04-13    50       2000

df %>%
  group_by(Stock) %>%
  mutate(keep = !any(Market.Cap > 1500 & Date == as.Date("2018-04-11"))) %>%
  filter(keep == TRUE)
```

Created on 2018-07-20 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: The link posted for group filter article is very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT:*** In case OP is looking for filtering only for specific date and with last column's value greater than 1500 following may help then.

```
subset(df122 , Market.Cap < 1500 | Date == as.Date("2018-04-11"))
```

---

With only using base `R`

```
tat <- apply(df122[4], 1, function(val) any(val < 1500))
df122[ tat , ]
```

Where your structure is getting stored in `df122`

Comment: This only removes rows where the value exceeds 1500, not all the rows of the same stock where that happens on a particular date.

Comment: @CalumYou, sorry I didn't get, when I checked it removed all the rows which have more than 1500 values in last column.

Comment: @CalumYou, I didn't include data comparison in my answer, please let me know if that is what you are referring? I didn't know OP need to have a specific date only in checks.

Comment: "because it's the only one with market cap > 1500 on 2018-04-11"

Comment: @sammyramz, could you please try EDIT code and let me know if this helps you?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 don't worry about it. Calum answered it. The idea is that the market cap must be a value less than 1500 only on a specific day, establishing the idea of a cutoff. Thanks for your help anyway.